# Is it possible that I can directly go to certain point during debug(for example, go to index=n)

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

I am debugging a recursion function in eclipse. This function is about to search through all the paths. So the problem is now the graph is too big and complicated, I just wanna to see certain point (after I reach the end of the recursion and I have an path_index which itself will decrement.) And I want to, say, directly go to the point when path_index is 9. So I am now at path_index==40, how can i directly go back to the state when the path_index is 9?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Conditional breakpoint? What IDE are you using?

Comment: "how can i directly go **back**" huh? You can't go back in time

Comment: Right-click on line number, add breakpoint, condition: path_index == 9

Comment: @Michael Actually in some debuggers you can go back in time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger#Reverse_debugging However, the usual approach is to re-run and stop earlier the next time.

Comment: @Michael Thx a lot!

Comment: @HansOlsson Huh, that's crazy. Thanks! I'm gonna see if I can play around with it over the weekend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a conditional breakpoint in eclipse with:

1) Right-click on line number

2) Add break point

3) Set condition: path_index == 9

4) Debug your program. It will stop at the beginning of `main`

5) Resume until you reach your break point. Conditional break points, which do not fulfill the condition, are skipped

Comment: Thx a lot! It works! :))